# A method to check if a Collection or Map is empty or null?

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, collections

I want to check if a Map, HashMap, ArrayList, List or anything from Collections is Empty or null?

I have this, but its not working when I pass a Map:

```
protected static <T extends Collection, Map> boolean isCollectionMapNullOrEmpty(final T c) {
  if (c == null) {
      return true;
  }

  return c.isEmpty();
 }
```

Failure:

```
  List<String> aList = Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "a4");
  Map<String, Object> aMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  aMap.put("a2", "foo");
  aMap.put("a1", "foo");
  aMap.put("a3", "foo");
  aMap.put("a4", "foo");
  System.out.println(isCollectionMapNullOrEmpty(aList));  // works

  // fails with The method isCollectionMapNullOrEmpty(T) in the type LearnHashMap is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,Object>)
  System.out.println(isCollectionMapNullOrEmpty(aMap));
```

Comment: `<T extends Collection, Map>` declares two type variables: `T` which is bounded by the raw `Collection`, and `Map` which is unbounded.

Comment: You can't do it without casting. Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Write two methods, one for maps and one for collections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `isCollectionMapNullOrEmpty` compiles and works, but not the way you intended.

```
<T extends Collection, Map>
```

You've declared two type variables, `T` and `Map`, where `T` must be a `Collection`.  The type variable `Map` has nothing to do with the interface `Map`, and is in fact not even used.  (Also, you used the raw `Collection` interface here.)  You are passing `aList` which is a `Collection`, so it compiles.  However, `aMap` is not a `Collection`, so the compilation fails passing in a `Map`.

It looks like you wanted `T` to be either a `Collection` *or* a `Map`.  But Java's generics don't work that way; you can't declare a type parameter to be one thing *or* another thing.

(As an aside, you can say one thing *and* another thing: `T extends Collection & Map`, or without raw types, `T extends Collection<?> & Map<?, ?>`, but I'm not aware of any classes that implement both interfaces.)

You can have two overloaded methods, one for a `Collection` and one for a `Map`, that will perform the same functionality.  Here, I've taken advantage of short-circuiting to combine the statements:

```
protected static boolean isCollectionMapNullOrEmpty(final Collection<?> c) {
    return c == null || c.isEmpty();
}
protected static boolean isCollectionMapNullOrEmpty(final Map<?, ?> m) {
    return m == null || m.isEmpty();
}
```

Both methods have the same exact code, but because there is no super-interface declaring `isEmpty`, this appears to be as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

You have the method ([link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty-java.util.Collection-)) :

> boolean org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Collection coll)

wich has null-safe check if the specified collection is empty.
This way you don't have to be checking for null values or defining custom methods

Answer (score 0):

if(storeMAPDetails.size==0)
You can do this directly to check that your map is empty or not !

Comment: And if it is null you get an NPE.